# Expectation over 2 random variables, help needed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Hi I am new here and I hope I can get some help.

My question is about taking expectation over random variables. Lets say I have two random variables $\Xi$ and $\theta$ where $\Xi$ is for example a poisson point process while $\theta$ is uniformly distributed random variable over $[-\pi,\pi]$. Assume that $\theta$ and $\Xi$ are independent random variables.

I have to find $$E_{\Xi,\theta}\big[ f(\theta, \Xi)\big]$$
Can I do the following
$$E_{\Xi,\theta}\big[ f(\theta, \Xi)\big]= E_{\Xi} \bigg[E_{\theta}\big[f(\theta,\Xi)\big]\bigg]=E_{\Xi}\bigg[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}f(\theta,\Xi)d\theta\bigg]   $$

My question is can I evaluate the integral inside the expectation and then take the expectation wrt to $\Xi$ or should I keep the integral over $[-\pi, \pi]$ and perform the expectation over $\Xi$ first then evaluate the integral?

Comment: The mathematical reason why it works is called Fubini's theorem. In the case of a Poisson process and a uniform variable, you can use Fubini's theorem in the case where both measure spaces are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickDaSilva. Can you given me examples where this  theorem doesnt work anymore?

Comment: Well, the hypotheses of the theorem goes as follow : you can apply it when both functions are either integrable or positive, and this works if the two spaces over which you are integrating are $\sigma$-finite or compact. If you work with real random variables (not in the sense that they take real values, but in the sense that the measure space over which they are defined is a subset of the reals), then $\sigma$-finiteness always holds. Same thing if you work over $\mathbb R^n$. So essentially you need not worry much about the hypotheses when you have an integrable/positive function.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva thank you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way should work.  They will be equivalent.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E_{\Xi,\Theta}\bigg[ f(\Theta, \Xi)\bigg] & = \mathsf E_{\Xi} \bigg[\mathsf E_{\Theta}\bigg[f(\Theta,\Xi)\bigg]\bigg]
& = \mathsf E_{\Theta} \bigg[\mathsf E_{\Xi}\bigg[f(\Theta,\Xi)\bigg]\bigg]
\\ &=\mathsf E_{\Xi}\bigg[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi}f(\theta,\Xi)\,\mathrm d\theta\bigg]
& = \mathsf E_\Theta\bigg[\sum_{\xi=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^\xi e^{-\lambda}}{\xi!}f(\Theta, \xi)\bigg]
\\ & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{\xi=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda^\xi e^{-\lambda}}{\xi!} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta,\xi)\,\mathrm d\theta\right)
 & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum_{\xi=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^\xi e^{-\lambda}}{\xi!} f(\theta,\xi)\right)\,\mathrm d\theta
\end{align}$$

Whether you integrate then sum, or sum then integrate, will depend on the function $f$ and which path it makes easiest.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I do have one more question if you dont mind. You see in the second step of the solution you provided assume BEFORE you evaluate the expectation wrt $\Xi$ you can evaluate the integral or simplify the integral. I am asking because after taking expectation wrt to $\Theta$ I can evaluate my function inside is special,is piecewise. Should I refer evaluating this integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ after the expectation wrt $\Xi$ or it doesnt  really matter @graham Kemp